# Be informed today's top question!

Tags: support, feature-request, hot-questions

I'm engaged in SO a lot of my time but not all of my time.

SO may have very important questions asked in the date of today which would be helpful for me too. So, I don't want to miss such important questions.

May I be informed  about such questions (at least 5 upvoted question only) at the end of time or just after the questions got 5 votes.

This would be really very nice feature if provided (But not through emails, just in my SO inbox).

---

And of-course I can search today's questions but I won't remember everyday, so if SO provides such feature would be nice to see.

Comment: All of the tools requested are there, just at your service!

Comment: Just subscribe to [the newsletter](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters).

Comment: @HansPassant To be fair, the newsletter isn't tag filtered. I'd count more on such like querying _highest voted_ or such with tag filters on.

Comment: I'd have to recommend the Buddhism site then.

Comment: How would one identify the most important questions?

Comment: at least 5 upvoted questions are must be important, no?

Comment: @C-linkNepal Search for highest voted questions filtered by tags, or make your own SQL query really filtering for everything you think that's _important_.

Comment: Notifications in the site inbox make little sense—you can already access this information though normal means on the site. The only way this feature request makes any sense is if you're asking for them to spam your email inbox. So -1 either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure your future is necessary as you can achieve that with features already exisiting on site.

There is a [*How do I search*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page that teaches you how to build your own queries for the SE search box.

Say your favorite tag is [C#] and you want to see the all the questions with 5+ votes which were posted during the last weekend; it does not get easier than:

> [[C#] is:question score:5..1000 created:2014-09-06..2014-09-07 closed:false](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5D+is%3Aquestion+score%3A5..1000+created%3A2014-09-06..2014-09-07+closed%3Afalse+)